# How to display geotagged photos from my domain in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, photos, geotag

I already asked a question similar to this then I used a plugin of displaying geotagged photos in leaflet from (Google+ photos|Instagram / CartoDB|Norvegiana ) [photos in leaflet](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/08/showing-geotagged-photos-on-leaflet-map.html) 
This plugin gets photos over the internet connection (Google+ photos|Instagram / CartoDB|Norvegiana ) I want the same but from photos hosted in my domain .

Comment: i tried the code but it dose not show the photos in my map and it shows this error: Cannot read property 'cluster' of undefined which is related to this line of code:
L.photo.cluster()
do i need to add additional leflet package in it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though all the examples on the Leaflet.Photo plugin page involve getting data via an API, all you really need is an array of objects with the latitude, longitude and URL(s) for each image. For example:

```js
var photos = [{
  "lat": 34.04555452,
  "lng": -118.3001509,
  "thumbnail": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo1_thumb.jpg",
  "url": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo1.jpg",
  "name": "My First Photo"
}, {
  "lat": 34.0522683,
  "lng": -118.2698607,
  "thumbnail": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo2_thumb.jpg",
  "url": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo2.jpg",
  "name": "My Second Photo"
}, {
  "lat": 34.06281904,
  "lng": -118.2809651,
  "thumbnail": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo3_thumb.jpg",
  "url": "http://www.mydomain.com/photo3.jpg",
  "name": "My Third Photo"
}]

var photoLayer = L.photo.cluster().on('click', function(evt) {
  var photo = evt.layer.photo;
  var template = '<img src="{url}" /></a><p>{name}</p>';
  evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(template, photo)).openPopup();
});

photoLayer.add(photos).addTo(map);
```

The `lat`, `lng` and `thumbnail` properties are required, since these are what the plugin uses to create the marker, but you can add any other properties you like, such as the full-size image URL, caption text, styling parameters, etc. The simplest way to use photos from your own domain is just to store this array of objects in your script, or as a separate file on your server, which you could load either with the page or later via AJAX.

Here's an example fiddle with the objects included in the script:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/q8ar6wu9/

Comment: It worked fine ,only one small issues the close popup images is not like usual  here the usual : http://i.imgur.com/PbSbiWq.png  and our close button :http://i.imgur.com/DuDmH2I.png

Comment: The author is using some custom css in those examples ([here](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Photo/blob/gh-pages/examples/css/map.css)). It's not really part of the plugin, but it does look nice, and probably makes it more mobile-friendly. If you use that css, you just need to add the `leaflet-popup-photo` class to your popup. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/t34qytf1/)

Comment: You are a master, It worked as I wanted .